# Equal height divs - complicated with multiple backgrounds

Tags: css, height, html, equals

I'm trying to create a website and it's design is forcing me to use multiple backgrounds. I'm talking about a technique that looks like this

```
    <div id="left">
         <div id="left_1">
              <div id="left_2">

              </div>
         </div>
    </div>

#left{
 width:235px; 
 margin:0; padding:0; float:left;
 background:url(../images/left_middle.jpg) top left repeat-y;
}
#left_1{
 width:235px; 
 margin:0; padding:0; float:left;
 background:url(../images/left_top.jpg) top left no-repeat;
}
#left_2{
 width:218px; 
 margin:0; padding:0 0 0 17px; float:left;
 background:url(../images/left_bottom.jpg) bottom left no-repeat;
}
```

At the same time a have to create an equal div/column height structure for the page.

```
<div id="container">

     <div id="left">
          <div id="left_1">
               <div id="left_2">

               </div>
          </div>
     </div>

     <div id="center">

     </div>

     <div id="right">
          <div id="right_1">
               <div id="right_2">

               </div>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

The #left, #center and #right divs should have the same height and look full with background. I have read a lot of techniques through internet about the equal-height-divs but adding the multiple backgrounds issue, makes it impossible for me to find a solution here.

I was wondering if someone could help me out there. Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: I'm confused. What's the multiple backgrounds problem you're having? It sounds like the column layout isn't a problem, but you say "The #left, #center and #right divs should ... look full with background" - what do you mean?

Comment: The left column uses three background images that look as one but also let the column height expand without causing any layout problem. One background image is repeated-y, one image always stays at the top of the div and one image always stays at the bottom.

The problem is that not only #left div should have the same height with the #center and #right, but #left1,#left2 and #left3 too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't mind using javascript/jquery, you can add this to your html:

```
<script type='text/javascript'
 src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {

    // get the heights
    l = $('#left_2').height();
    r = $('#right_2').height();
    c = $('#center').height();

    // get maximum heights of all columns
    h = Math.max(c, Math.max(l, r));

    // apply it
    $('#left_2').height(h);
    $('#right_2').height(h);
    $('#center').height(h);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I tested what you suggested and it works fine:) Do you think it's risky to use javascript for this issue?

Comment: well, as far as i can tell, no risk at all, as most modern browsers support this, and most people probably enable it [citation needed :P]

there are several css only solutions, tho. but sometimes when background images are involved, it's getting tricky, especially cos we have to deal with cross-browsers compatibility.

anyhow, check these out:
- http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/61
- http://redmelon.net/tstme/3cols2/
- http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200405/equal_height_boxes_with_css/
- http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

Answer (score 1):

Save yourself the trouble and just use tables for the outer layout.  They just work.

Here's the table example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
<title>left</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .side { background-color:blue;color:white;width:235px;vertical-align:top;margin:0px;padding:0px;}
        .left3 {padding:0px 0px 0px 17px;vertical-align:top;}
        .mainContent {margin:0px;vertical-align:top;}
        table {width:100%;height:100%;border-collapse:collapse;}
        html,body{width:100%;height:100%;margin:0px;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="side">left
            <table>
                <tr><td class="side">left side 2
                    <table><tr><td class="left3">Left Side 3</td></tr></table>
                </td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td class="mainContent">center</td>
        <td class="side">right</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you mean replacing "all" divs by tables and cells or just "some specific" divs?

Comment: +1 for reality-based answer. Sometimes div/css layouts are more trouble than they are worth.

Comment: @ktsixit: I generally use a combination of tables and divs.  In this case I would use tables to get the heights exactly as I need them.  Most of the content areas inside I would do as divs so that they could adjust as necessary.

Comment: @Chris Lively, I tested the table solution but it works only in firefox. In IE and all other browsers, the tables and cells inside the main wrap table, don't expand their height 100%. They behave just like divs, adjusting their height depending on their contents. Although I have set "height:100%" for all tables and cells.

Comment: @ktsixit: Just added sample code. It works in IE8, FF3.6, Chrome, and Safari. I don't know about other versions of IE or FF because I don't have them. But considering it's HTML 4.01 Strict, their rendering engines ought to do just fine.

Comment: I just saw the new example code you posted. I'll test it. My test version was a bit different that yours